# DataFrame wide to long with hierarchies given by relative position of row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to reshape my pandas dataframe from wide to long (I know kind of a ridiculously easy task - sorry for that - but I am completely stuck right now).

Problem is, that the categorical affiliation is not unambiguously given by a variable but by the relative position within the dataframe. Meaning the description of one row defines the subcategory of all following rows of higher hierarchy, until a variable of the same hierarchy as the one defining the subcategory starts the next one, etc.

Guess it's easiest described with an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Category': ['Fruits', 'Apple', 'Green', 'Red', 'Pineapple', 'Banana', 'Vegetables', 'Potatoes', 'Salad', 'Meat'],
                          'Value': [10, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3],
                          'Hierarchy': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]})

df
Out[87]: 
     Category  Value  Hierarchy
0      Fruits     10          1
1       Apple      5          2
2       Green      2          3
3         Red      3          3
4   Pineapple      3          2
5      Banana      2          2
6  Vegetables      4          1
7    Potatoes      2          2
8       Salad      2          2
9        Meat      3          1
```

What I want should look something like this:

```
     Value   Hierarchy1  Hierarchy2  Hierarchy3
1        2       Fruits       Apple       Green      
2        3       Fruits       Apple         Red
3        3       Fruits      Fruits   Pineapple
4        2       Fruits      Fruits      Banana
5        2   Vegetables  Vegetables    Potatoes
6        2   Vegetables  Vegetables       Salad
7        3         Meat        Meat        Meat
```

Importantly, it should work for an infinite amount of hierarchy-levels.

As I see it, `df.wide_to_long()` does not have this functionality built in and the only custom solution I could come up with (which is not even working yet) were loops with if statements.

Any idea of a better approach than that or even some built in functionality I did oversee?

Comment: not clear how Pineapple or Banana end up in the Hierarchy2 when there is none of them in the Hierarchy column with value 2 in the input

Comment: Now that I read it again, I don't think wide to long is actually the right description. But it's also not long to wide. Anyways, couldn't find the functionality withing df.groupby(), nor df.pivot() either.

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the reply. Well since there is no higher Hierarchy directly following onto the Pineapple and Banana row, they make up the most granular level for their categories.

Comment: Then I don't get the logic, sorry

Comment: Perhaps is better if write an explanation with examples in your question

Comment: Well I guess the structure is not particularly logical from a data processing perspective. The above is obviously just an example to illustrate the structure of more complex financial data I download from Bloomberg, which presents it in an easy way to read, not to work with it.

Comment: Maybe it makes it clearer with his example:  Region Value Hierarchy
0 Products 297392.0 1
1    iPhone 191973.0 2
2    Wearables, Home and Accessories 38367.0 2
3    Mac 35190.0 2
4    iPad 31862.0 2
5 Services 68425.0 1
So rows 1 - 4 are all products and therefore belong to subcategory 0. I'd like to present it as a plotly sunburst chart (https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/) which needs the data in this format if I read it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sunburst could be drawn by `parent`-`child` and `value`, just like **Graph Theory**, we only concern the relationship between nodes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Category': ['Fruits', 'Apple', 'Green', 'Red', 'Pineapple', 'Banana', 'Vegetables', 'Potatoes', 'Salad', 'Meat'],
                          'Value': [10, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3],
                          'Hierarchy': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]})
print(df)
###
     Category  Value  Hierarchy
0      Fruits     10          1
1       Apple      5          2
2       Green      2          3
3         Red      3          3
4   Pineapple      3          2
5      Banana      2          2
6  Vegetables      4          1
7    Potatoes      2          2
8       Salad      2          2
9        Meat      3          1
```

We can use matrix cross manipulation to find the parent of each `Category`

```
v = df['Hierarchy'].values[:, None]
print(v)
###
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [3]
 [2]
 [2]
 [1]
 [2]
 [2]
 [1]]
```

```
h = df['Hierarchy'].values
print(h)
###
[1 2 3 3 2 2 1 2 2 1]
```

```
m = h - v > 0
m[np.tril_indices(m.shape[1])] = False
print(m)
###
[[False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]]
```

In every column's last `True` indicates the parent's index

```
occ = np.argwhere(m == True)
df['parent'] = pd.DataFrame(occ).groupby(1).last()
print(df)
###
     Category  Value  Hierarchy  parent
0      Fruits     10          1     NaN
1       Apple      5          2     0.0
2       Green      2          3     1.0
3         Red      3          3     1.0
4   Pineapple      3          2     0.0
5      Banana      2          2     0.0
6  Vegetables      4          1     NaN
7    Potatoes      2          2     6.0
8       Salad      2          2     6.0
9        Meat      3          1     NaN
```

Find their corresponding parents

```
df['parent'] = df['parent'].map(df['Category'].to_dict())
print(df)
###
     Category  Value  Hierarchy      parent
0      Fruits     10          1         NaN
1       Apple      5          2      Fruits
2       Green      2          3       Apple
3         Red      3          3       Apple
4   Pineapple      3          2      Fruits
5      Banana      2          2      Fruits
6  Vegetables      4          1         NaN
7    Potatoes      2          2  Vegetables
8       Salad      2          2  Vegetables
9        Meat      3          1         NaN
```

Plot

```
fig = px.sunburst(
    df,
    names='Category',
    parents='parent',
    values='Value',
    color='Value',
    template='simple_white',
    width=800,
    height=800
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Color without value

```
fig = px.sunburst(
    df,
    names='Category',
    parents='parent',
    values='Value',
    # color='Value',
    template='seaborn',
    width=800,
    height=800
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes along and has a similar problem, this is my custom solution for it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Category': ['Fruits', 'Apple', 'Green', 'Red', 'Pineapple', 'Banana', 'Vegetables', 'Potatoes', 'Soft', 'Hard', 'Salade', 'Meat'],
                          'Value': [10, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3],
                          'Hierarchy': [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]})


def c_sunburst(df):
    # Find different hierarchy levels
    levels = [x for x in df['Hierarchy'].unique()]
    # Reshape df to reflect hierarchies in wide format
    df_wide = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Hierarchy ' + str(level): [] for level in levels})
    df_wide['Value'] = []
    
    for i in range(len(df) - 1): # i is index run variable
        if not df['Hierarchy'][i] < df['Hierarchy'][i + 1]: # Excludes all rows that are not most granular level
            ind = i
            hierarchies = []
            while(df['Hierarchy'][ind] > 1):
                hierarchies = [df[list(df)[0]][max([x for x in list(range(0, ind)) if df['Hierarchy'][x] < df['Hierarchy'][i]])]] + hierarchies
                ind = max([x for x in list(range(0, ind)) if df['Hierarchy'][x] < df['Hierarchy'][i]])
            hierarchies = hierarchies + [df[list(df)[0]][i]]
            rows = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Hierarchy ' + str(level): [hi] for level, hi in zip(levels, hierarchies)})
            rows['Value'] = df['Value'][i]
            df_wide = pd.concat([df_wide, rows], ignore_index = True)
    # Add last df row, which is always most granular level
    ind = len(df) - 1
    i = ind
    hierarchies = []
    while(df['Hierarchy'][ind] > 1):
        hierarchies = [df[list(df)[0]][max([x for x in list(range(0, ind)) if df['Hierarchy'][x] < df['Hierarchy'][i]])]] + hierarchies
        ind = max([x for x in list(range(0, ind)) if df['Hierarchy'][x] < df['Hierarchy'][i]])
    hierarchies = hierarchies + [df[list(df)[0]][i]]
    rows = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Hierarchy ' + str(level): [hi] for level, hi in zip(levels, hierarchies)})
    rows['Value'] = df['Value'][i]
    df_wide = pd.concat([df_wide, rows], ignore_index = True)
    
    return(df_wide)
```

This adds NaN instead of carrying less granularly defined categories all the way through but changing this is obv a minor task which I leave to you.